# Is there a way to switch to a user of a remote machine like normal user?

Tags: 20.04, ssh, remote-desktop, raspberrypi, remote-access

I am planning to use a Raspberry Pi as my secondary pc(Ubuntu). Like how I switch to users on my primary machine(Ubuntu 20.04 ) navigating to the top bar, clicking on the Power Icon then selecting switch user from the dropdown menu, would it be possible to switch to a user of my secondary machine from my primary machine and start using as I'm using my secondary machine?
If there is no such way how could I have nearest experience?

N.B: Both machines would use the same wifi network

Comment: What would you expect that to do? I mean, you have two separate machines, so what functionality are you expecting here? Do you want to open a new session on the secondary machine and see it in your primary machine's monitor? How will the two machines be connected? Please [edit] your question and explain what you want to achieve in more detail.

Comment: If you ssh into the remote machine you can use the `su` command to switch to another user. See the man page for all the details